# DepthImageFrame Kinect V2

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect-sdk

Help!

I am trying to access the `DeapthImageFrame` class from `Microsoft.Kinect` in Kinect v2 but it keeps saying that I am missing a reference. I cannot do something as simple as:

```
int player = depthFrame[i16] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;
int realDepth = depthFrame[i16] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth;
```

I am not able to use the `DepthImageFrame` or `DeapthStream`, and I am not even able to enable it. I have tried so many examples and none work because of missing reference.

Any idea? 
How can I fix this issue? 
Do I need any library? If so what libraries and where can I find them?

Your help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The api for Kinect v2 is completely different from the previous versions. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.aspx

for depth take a look at

[DepthFrameReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.depthframereader.aspx)
and 
[DepthFrame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.depthframe.aspx)

In particular to get the latest depth frame `DepthFrameReader.AcquireLatestFrame()`.

Answer (score 0):

to Developing Kinect V2 you need use SDK2. 
if you already installed SDK2 you just need remove Microsoft.Kinect namespace from your references on your visual studio then brows for Microsoft.Kinect and define it as new references